# Previous month values in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, window-functions

I am trying to find the previous month score for each category from the below table in Bigquery.

| year | category | period | period_type | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | A |  | MTD | 100 |
|  | B |  | MTD | 200 |
|  | C |  | MTD | 300 |
|  | D |  | MTD | 400 |
|  | E |  | MTD | 500 |
| 2023 | A | 1 | MTD | 300 |
| 2023 | A | 2 | MTD | 500 |
| 2023 | A | 4 | MTD | 600 |
| 2023 | D | 4 | MTD | 30 |
| 2023 | D | 7 | MTD | 300 |
| 2023 | D | 8 | MTD | 120 |

This is the code I am using(I have added the table data in the CTE using union all commands for the ease of users) -

```
with cte as (
SELECT null AS year, 'A' AS category, null AS period, 'MTD' AS period_type, 100 AS score
UNION ALL
SELECT null AS year, 'B' AS category, null AS period, 'MTD' AS period_type, 200 AS score
UNION ALL
SELECT null AS year, 'C' AS category, null AS period, 'MTD' AS period_type, 300 AS score
UNION ALL
SELECT null AS year, 'D' AS category, null AS period, 'MTD' AS period_type, 400 AS score
UNION ALL
SELECT null AS year, 'E' AS category, null AS period, 'MTD' AS period_type, 500 AS score
UNION ALL
SELECT '2023' AS year, 'A' AS category, 1 AS period, 'MTD' AS period_type, 300 AS score
UNION ALL
SELECT '2023' AS year, 'A' AS category, 2 AS period, 'MTD' AS period_type, 500 AS score
UNION ALL
SELECT '2023' AS year, 'A' AS category, 4 AS period, 'MTD' AS period_type, 600 AS score
UNION ALL
SELECT '2023' AS year, 'D' AS category, 4 AS period, 'MTD' AS period_type, 30 AS score
UNION ALL
SELECT '2023' AS year, 'D' AS category, 7 AS period, 'MTD' AS period_type, 300 AS score
UNION ALL
SELECT '2023' AS year, 'D' AS category, 8 AS period, 'MTD' AS period_type, 120 AS score
)

SELECT *,
cast(year as INT)*12 + period as gen_order,
sum(score) over(previous_month range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_month,
lag(score) over(previous_row) as prev_row

FROM cte
WINDOW 
previous_month as (partition by category order by (cast(year as INT)*12 + period)),
previous_row as(partition by category order by (cast(year as INT)*12 + period))
ORDER BY category;
```

I am able to get the previous month score, **but interestingly for records where year and period is NULL, the score of the same row is being generated as previous month result**. How is this possible?  Isn't it supposed to be NULL, as generated by the lag function(also in the code for comparison). How is `sum(score) over(previous_month range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding)` generating the value from the same row when the order by value is NULL? `range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding` is non-inclusive of the current row as seen in all the other cases right? Can someone please explain the reasons behind this?

The output I am getting is given below -

| year | category | period | period_type | score | gen_order | prev_month | prev_row |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | A |  | MTD | 100 |  | 100 |  |
| 2023 | A | 1 | MTD | 300 | 24277 |  | 100 |
| 2023 | A | 2 | MTD | 500 | 24278 | 300 | 300 |
| 2023 | A | 4 | MTD | 600 | 24280 |  | 500 |
|  | B |  | MTD | 200 |  | 200 |  |
|  | C |  | MTD | 300 |  | 300 |  |
|  | D |  | MTD | 400 |  | 400 |  |
| 2023 | D | 4 | MTD | 30 | 24280 |  | 400 |
| 2023 | D | 7 | MTD | 300 | 24283 |  | 30 |
| 2023 | D | 8 | MTD | 120 | 24284 | 300 | 300 |
|  | E |  | MTD | 500 |  | 500 |  |